# Clone parts of a Tree starting from selected leafs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, tree

I'm building a Tree structure of node objects as follows:

```
function Node(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.selected = false;
    this.children = [];
}

Node.prototype.addChild = function () {
    var l = this.children.push(new Node(this));
    return this.children[l-1];
};

Node.prototype.bfs = function(callback) {
    var queue=[this], n;
    while(queue.length > 0) {
        n = queue.shift();
        callback(n);
        if(n.children.length == 0) continue;
        for (var i = 0; i< n.children.length; i++) {
            queue.push(n.children[i]);
        }
    }
};

var root = new Node(null);
var nodeA = root.addChild();
var nodeB = root.addChild();
var nodeAA = nodeA.addChild();
var nodeAB = nodeA.addChild();
var nodeBA = nodeB.addChild();
var nodeBB = nodeB.addChild();
```

Now, i'm selecting some nodes:

```
nodeAA.selected = true;
```

I'm able to find out the selected nodes through a BFS:

```
root.bfs(function(node){
    console.log(node, node.selected);
});
```

... and it is also very easy to mark as selected all the corresponding parent nodes until the root:

```
var n = node;
do {
    n.selected = true;
    n = n.parentNode;
} while (n);
```

Now, i need to create a clone of the initial Tree structure with the selected leafs and the corresponding parent nodes, but i'm not able to reassign the new child nodes to their respective new parents.

Trying with JSON.stringify() leads to the circular reference error.

How can i reconstruct a clone of my initial Tree with just only the branches with the selected leafs?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the existing tree can be pruned to exclude the not selected leaf paths a `dfs` would do it.

Drawbacks :

1. The existing tree is modified
2. The pruned children will still exist as a entry in the children array with `null` value. Can be overcome by using a data structure that supports `O(1)` deletion and insertion

**Psuedo Code**

```
Prune-UnSelected-Leaf(root)

if(root) == null return null

if(root.children.length == 0) //Check if node is a Leaf
  if(root.selected)
    return root // Keep this node
  else 
    return null; // Ignore the node
bool AnyChildSelected = false
for(i : 1 to children.Length)
  var childSelectedNode = Prune-UnSelected-Leaf(children[i])
  if(childSelectedNode)
    AnyChildSelected = true
  root.children[i] = childSelectedNode

if(AnyChildSelected == true || node.selected == true) // Keep the node
  return node
else 
  return null; // Ignore the node
```

Suppose the was such.

> ```
>         Root Node
>         /   |    \
>        /    |     \
>     A(T)   B(F)    C(F)
>     /              /  
>   D(F)            E(T)
> ```

After running the algorithm the unselected paths are set to null and will look like this

> ```
>            Root Node
>           /   X      \   
> Return A /    X(null) \ Return C
>       A(T)   B(F)    C(F)
>       X              /  
>      X Return null  /  Return E
>     D(F)          E(T)
> ```

You can also modify the above algorithm to clone the tree without modifying the existing tree.

Overload for `addChild` to append a existing child Node to parent

```
addChild(child)
  child.parent = this
  l = this.children.push(child);
  return this.children[l-1];
```

Let `Clone-Node(node)` be a function that takes a node and create a deep copy with information related to the node but initialize empty/default for `parent`, `children` and `selected` attributes

```
Clone-Tree(root)

if(root) == null return null

if(root.children.length == 0) //Check if node is a Leaf
  if(root.selected)
    return Clone-Node(root) // Keep this node
  else 
    return null; // Ignore the node

bool AnyChildSelected = false
parent = Clone-Node(root)

for(i : 1 to children.Length)
  var childSelectedNode = Clone-Tree(children[i])
  if(childSelectedNode != null)
    AnyChildSelected = true
    parent.AddChild(childSelectedNode) // Add child to new parent 

if(AnyChildSelected == true || root.selected == true) // Keep the node
  return parent
else 
  return null; // Ignore the node
```